# Java applet scrollbar

Tags: java, applet

[Thanks for the answers. This comes for you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo0Cazxj_yc ]
This might and should be a very easy question, but i could not find a solution.

I have a java applet, and i want a vertical scrollbar so that i can load thousands of buttons into the applet and use the scrollbar to see buttons down on the applet[image: rightnow it looks like this].

Buttons are used to select items. if button is pressed, the item is selected.

When i load buttons, all of them are shown on one screen, squeezed together to fit the screen in width and height (~1000px,~1000px).  Below code is a portion of my program. Please comment.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    NameClassifier nameClassifier = new NameClassifier();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(nameClassifier);
     scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.getContentPane().add(nameClassifier);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("exiting");
```

Comment: For better help sooner. post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Note that I completed an SSCCE from your snippets in around 35 lines of code.

Comment: BTW - why do you make continual references to 'applet' when the code uses a 'frame'?

Comment: "thousands of buttons .. used to select items."  That sounds like it is better suited to a `JList` component with multiple selection enabled.

Comment: Andrew You are right, I should have added the NameClassifier part. Also, This is the first time I had to use Applets, I do not know the difference between them and frames

Comment: An applet is (usually) embedded in a web page.  A `Frame` or `JFrame` is free floating on the desktop.  I *strongly* suggest you avoid applets if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ManyButtons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                NameClassifier nameClassifier = new NameClassifier();
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(nameClassifier);
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                    ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                frame.add(scrollPane);
                // nameClassifier has already been added to the scroll pane.
                //frame.getContentPane().add(nameClassifier);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("exiting");
            }
        });
    }
}

class NameClassifier extends JPanel {

    NameClassifier() {
        super(new GridLayout(0,10,2,2));
        for (int ii=1; ii<=1000; ii++) {
            add(new JButton("Button " + ii));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use a [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't add anything directly to the frame, so

```
frame.add(scrollPane);
```

is wrong.

Add things to the content pane. probably

```
scrollPane.add(nameClassifier);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

btw, that is one pretty gui design. :)

Comment: -1, it is not wrong to add components directly to the frame. This has been supported since JDK5.

Comment: MeBigFatGuy, I would love to share this great design with the world, but alas only I will use it.